# Form tag breaking nav template in chrome

Tags: html, css, forms

When I had a simple form tag around my inputs my navbar breaks but there is no CSS linked to the form element. I've validated my html with the w3c validator and everything is fine. I don't really know how to fix this, I've tried so many things. This only happens in Chrome.

[Without the form tag (good looking one)](http://jimmyhoule.net/form-issue/withoutform.html)

[With the form tag (broken one)](http://jimmyhoule.net/form-issue/withform.html)

My eternal gratitude to anyone who try to help, I've been trying to fix this for hours and didnt find anything on the web to help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some additional css you need to add:

```
.main-head{
  height: 149px;
}

.logo{
   float:left;
}
```

Comment: more like 142px but thanks, it works. Still I dont really get why it brokes just by adding the form tag (a div tag wouldnt make it break).

Answer (score 0):

Add this both classes in your css-

```
a.logo{float:left;}
.container:after {content: '';clear: both;display: block;}
```

Hope it will helps you

Comment: This helps. But I still dont get why it broke.

Answer (score -1):

I would use this instead :

```
.container {position: relative;}
.main-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

It's compatible to all browsers